# How can I store big Chemical Splash and Impact Goggles?

Tags: eyeglasses

My grandparents bought [3M's Splash Goggles](https://www.3mcanada.ca/3M/en_CA/company-ca/all-3m-products/%7E/3M-Chemical-Splash-and-Impact-Goggles-93506H1-DC-clear-lens/?N=5002385+8711017+3290534590+3294529206&rt=rud) to try to [prevent SARS-CoV-2 entering their eyes](https://www.webmd.com/eye-health/covid-19-and-your-eyes#1), for they can't find any store that sells full face respirators to individuals , not even Amazon! They're stunned that 3M hasn't accompanied it with a case to store them. They're afraid of buying one off Amazon.com, because they don't know if a case by some random manufacturer is big enough to contain these Splash Goggles. They can't find any open retailer in Canada that sells them.

1. What are some workarounds to a Goggles Case?
2. How can they check, without examining in person or in hand, if a Goggles Case on Amazon is big enough to contain these Splash Goggles?
   [image]

Comment: There are fitted cases available for them if you buy them all from the same source and with the replaceable lenses made to fit them. The case is black tough plastic similar to first aid kits and about the same size. Look for laser safety goggles and prepare to spend ~$100. They come in a handy case.

Comment: You just do what any building contractor would do; toss them on a workbench somewhere. The punishment these things take is phenomenal - you don't need to treat them like rare bird eggs. Why do they think they will contract COVID19 through their eyes anyway? It's stated to be a fairly unlikely transmission vector compared to nose and mouth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grandparents can relax their relentless search for a specific storage case.

**HACK**: Find a zip-lock plastic bag big enough to hold your grandparents' goggles. This will be sufficient to protect the eyewear from all but a direct meteor strike. They are clean and dust resistant so long as the seal remains closed. They won't scratch the goggles lens.

You can find the size by comparing the length of the goggles to the length of the box of zip-lock bags. They're available in most any grocery store convenient to where  <strike>you</strike>  they live.

When you want another storage case, pull another one out of the box. The bags are made by a variety of different manufacturers and in different thicknesses. Use one bag per pair of goggles to make handling more manageable.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If it's about protecting the goggles from scratches, your grandma can knit a fluffy drawstring bag for them. I suggest using either thick yarn or a very thick pattern like patent or cabe knit. This is a good way to use some leftover yarn and it adds a lovely personal touch to this otherwise grim situation.

I've kept my phone in a drawstring bag knit from plushy sock yarn for several years and there's not a single scratch on the display. And you can use the bag to wipe the phone/goggles clean.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of buying a dedicated glasses case for the goggles, you/they can buy any box which is big enough and not overly big. I would start looking at the freezer and lunch box section of the shops.

Such a box is likely to be overly big, fill the extra space with kitchen paper or a piece of cloth which can be replaced at each use or which can be cleaned.

If they prefer to buy online they can go by the measurements of the box as given and the measurements of the googles, as measured by themselves. I would prefer to buy from a shop where you can check out the shape and quality of the box.